# Python trim space based on condition

Tags: python

I have the following string.

```
yesterday webcast featuring $ aapl $ wynn $ goog $ lgf trader education
```

I wish to combine the "$" sign and the succeeding word and produce the output as follows:

```
yesterday webcast featuring $aapl $wynn $goog $lgf trader education
```

Is there any generic function instead of writing a loop to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `my_string.replace('$ ', '$')`? If you need it to be more specific/context-sensitive, you can also use regex replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using regex in order to keep your solution less brittle.

```
import re
s = "yesterday webcast featuring $ aapl $ wynn $ goog $ lgf $   ibm trader education"
n = re.sub(r'\$\s*', '$', s)
print(n)
```

Results in:

```
yesterday webcast featuring $aapl $wynn $goog $lgf $ibm trader education
```